# VPN Routing Challenge - Multiple Interfaces

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

I have a mac-mini running Ubuntu desktop 18.04 LTS.

The device has the following adapters:

- Built in Ethernet which is the main local LAN connection
- Thunderbolt Ethernet Adapter - Connected Directly to the TV.

I want to make it such that the connection from the TV gets routed through an Open VPN tunnel (to enable overseas TV).

(Any ideas how I would do this? The mac-mini has a wireless adapter I am not using if that helps the config?)

Comment: You should add more info about what have you done to research this topic and what steps you have tried?! And where did you get stuck!?

Comment: You want a VPN just for the TV or would you mind if everything went though VPN?